# Unclear why "adjust = "tukey" was changed to "sidak""

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, tukey-hsd-test, lsmeans

I noticed a strange behavior for `cld` function when making multiple comparisons.

When I use `cld(EMM, adjust = "tukey")` it gives me a warning that `adjust = "tukey" was changed to "sidak"`.
However, if I omit the `adjust = "tukey"`, it applies the Tukey correction without any warning.

1. What does it mean `"tukey" is only appropriate for one set of pairwise comparisons`? I know that Tukey is appropriate when the design is balanced, homoscedastic and when we do all pairwise comparisons. However, it is not clear to me what `one set of pairwise comparisons` means.
2. Why does the function automatically switch to Sidak? Is Sidak the best choice in this case? Because Sidak assumes the individual tests are independent.

Below you will find a reproducible example

```
library(emmeans)
library(multcomp)

set.seed(1)
DF = data.frame(G1 = factor(rep(letters[1:2],each = 10)),
     G2 = factor(rep(letters[3:4],10)), VAL = rnorm(20))
LM = lm(VAL ~ G1 * G2, data = DF)
EMM = emmeans(LM, ~ G1 * G2);EMM

 G1 G2  emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 a  c  -0.0139 0.427 16   -0.919    0.891
 b  c   0.5641 0.427 16   -0.341    1.469
 a  d   0.2783 0.427 16   -0.626    1.183
 b  d  -0.0664 0.427 16   -0.971    0.838

Confidence level used: 0.95 

cld(EMM, adjust = "tukey")
Note: adjust = "tukey" was changed to "sidak"
because "tukey" is only appropriate for one set of pairwise comparisons

 G1 G2  emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
 b  d  -0.0664 0.427 16   -1.263     1.13  1    
 a  c  -0.0139 0.427 16   -1.210     1.18  1    
 a  d   0.2783 0.427 16   -0.918     1.47  1    
 b  c   0.5641 0.427 16   -0.633     1.76  1    

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: sidak method for 4 estimates 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 
significance level used: alpha = 0.05 

cld(EMM)

 G1 G2  emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
 b  d  -0.0664 0.427 16   -0.971    0.838  1    
 a  c  -0.0139 0.427 16   -0.919    0.891  1    
 a  d   0.2783 0.427 16   -0.626    1.183  1    
 b  c   0.5641 0.427 16   -0.341    1.469  1    

Confidence level used: 0.95 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 
significance level used: alpha = 0.05
```

Comment: I will investigate the inconsistency - a code logic issue, not a statistical one. BTW, I suggest not using cld. It is a poor way to summarize comparisons because it highlights non-findings rather than findings.

Comment: Oh, duh! See my addition to the answer. There is nothing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, (1) is why. The Tukey adjustment is not appropriate except in the context if all pairwise comparisons of one set of means, because of the correlation structure that implies.

When it is not one set of pairwise comparisons, then the code replaces tukey with sidak, because that is a reasonable adjustment that can always be used for any set of contrasts. It is a conservative adjustment under very broad conditions.

#### On the apparent inconsistency you see

Look at the output closely and read the annotations carefully. *Both* outputs show that the Tukey adjustment was used for the *pairwise comparisons* (the latter performed under the hood by `cld`). In the first output, the annotation says that the Sidak adjustment was applied to the *confidence intervals*, meaning the CIs displayed in the table which are not for the pairwise comparisons but for the individual means. The reason this happened is because `adjust = "tukey"` was added to the call and that adjustment was attempted for *both* the means and the pairwise comparisons. Note that the two outputs show difference confidence limits.

So I think there is no error or inconsistency here. The only thing I find wanting is that annotations mentioning P values are potentially confusing because they are invisible and not shown explicitly in the output. I will see if it is practical to provide clearer annotations that more clearly reference the grouping part of the display.

Providing for CLDs *at all* remains one of my biggest regrets in developing this package.

Comment: But when I use `cld( emmeans(LM, ~ G1 * G2) )` I'm testing all six pairwise combinations, so I thought Tukey may apply. In addition, when I use `pairs( emmeans(LM, ~ G1 * G2),  adjust = "tukey" )`, I do not receive any warning.

Comment: That's because pairs() only does the pairwise comparisons. cld() displays the means, CIs for those means, as well as groupings based n the pairwise comparisons.

Comment: In this case if this happen how can be reported? Sidak or Tukey??

Comment: Report the method that was actually used.